# iterrows() : gives the same result for every row

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I'm trying to create the autocovariance for several lags on several rows. 
In this example I got two rows and 11 lags.

I got the following two rows in my example:

[image]

in text:

```
 array([[164, 148, 152, 144, 155, 125, 153, 146, 138, 190, 192, 192],
   [239, 379, 105, 150, 400, 326, 134, 441, 199, 431, 203, 425]], dtype=int64)
```

I want to get the autocovariance for every row with lag 0,1...11.

For now, I got the following code:

```
 import statsmodels as sm
 import numpy as np
 import pandas as pd
 df = pd.read_excel("directory\\file.xlsx")

def autocov(row):
    x = sm.tsa.stattools.acovf(df.T[row], unbiased=False, demean=True, 
    fft=None, missing='none')
    autocov_df = pd.DataFrame(x)

for index,row in df.iterrows():
     print(x)
```

This prints me the following array:

[image: output]

in text:

```
 [ 447.52083333  191.93229167   94.51041667  -26.36979167  -87.58333333
   -97.90104167 -121.86458333  -54.328125    -94.47916667  -31.19270833
   -12.65625      16.171875  ]
 [ 447.52083333  191.93229167   94.51041667  -26.36979167  -87.58333333
   -97.90104167 -121.86458333  -54.328125    -94.47916667  -31.19270833
  -12.65625      16.171875  ]
```

However, as you can see, it prints the same values for both 2 rows.

What am I doing wrong in my code???

This is my preferred output:

```
[ 447.52083333  191.93229167   94.51041667  -26.36979167  -87.58333333
  -97.90104167 -121.86458333  -54.328125    -94.47916667  -31.19270833
  -12.65625      16.171875  ]
[ 14887., -7237., 1811.,-198.5,
  2903.08333333,  -3346.41666667,   1140.33333333,  -1207.25      ,
  1141.08333333,  -3307.75      ,   1402.33333333,   -544.41666667]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating with `index, row` but you print constant value:

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    print(autocov_df.T)
```

`autocov_df.T` does not depend on `index` or `row`.

You need to use iteration variable to see difference, like:

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    y = some_function(index,row)
    print(y)
```

In your example you don't call `autocov` and there is no return statement in that function:

```
def autocov(row):
    x = sm.tsa.stattools.acovf(df.T[row], unbiased=False, demean=True, 
    fft=None, missing='none')
    autocov_df = pd.DataFrame(x)
    return(autocov_df)

for index,row in df.iterrows():
     x = autocov(index)
     print(x)
```

Note that your parameter naming could be misleading.

Comment: What would you like to print?

Comment: I edited my question with the preferred output. This is what I want to achieve (my df will eventually have thousands of rows)

Comment: I tried your solution and embedded it in my code like this:

for index,row in df.iterrows():
    print(row)
    print(autocov_df)

It gives me the same results however

Comment: Answer is updated. Needed to import `statsmodels.tsa.stattools` to run example.